# CSS a:current feature

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to use the a:current attribute to change the style of 
the element . But the problem is that the a href cannot be 
made to point to another page .
So I created something like this .

```
      <a  class='linkstyl' href="#1" >A</a>
      <a  class='linkstyl' href="#2" >B</a>
      <a class='linkstyl' href="#3" >C</a>
```

My css file is something like this

```
     .linkstyl{
            cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;
            color: #ccc;


        }
     .linkstyl:current{
            cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;
            color: #aaa;


        }
```

But the current feature doesn't work as thought , how to rectify it ?

Comment: Quick googling doesn't turn up any references to `:current`. Are you using some library that enables this or is my google-fu just weak?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `:current`. How is it different than `:hover` and `:active`?

Comment: Do you mean [`:target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo)?

Comment: Even so, `:target` doesn't apply to `href="#"`, but to `name` or `id`. But it's the closest guess.

Comment: Oh it's a pseudo-class that was added to the CSS4 spec a couple of weeks ago. And people are already asking about it? I should probably tell the CSS working group to keep everything under wraps instead, until it's ready. In the meantime, -1 for jumping the gun by a good couple of years.

Answer (score 3):

Unless this is brand new, there is no CSS psuedo selector `:current`. You may be thinking of `:active` or `:focus`.

`:focus` will not be applied however, once the element loses focus, for example if you click anywhere else on the page.

`:active` is only applied when the element is "activated", usually that just means while the mouse is being clicked or similar.

Here's a demo with both so you can see if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/HW8X6/

**Side note**: `id` or `name` attributes should not start with a number, you may want to change them from 1, 2, and 3 to something like `item-1`, `item-2`, `item-3`.

Comment: Turns out `:current` was pretty new: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#time-pseudos

Answer (score 2):

You are completely missing the point of this "time-linear presentation" pseudo-class.
Try to read the [current draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#current-pseudo) of the Selectors Level 4 specification again.

What are you trying to select with `.linkstyl:current`?
You know that no recent browsers support it, right?
[`a:local-link`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#here-pseudo) is probably what you really wanted.

Comment: That wasn't there before. I guess they're actively updating it.